# "ValueError: Unrecognized marker style 'hline' ". A bunch of markers not being recognised by Matplotlib plot() and scatter() functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

The following list of markers given in the ['matplotlib.markers' documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers) are not being recognised by both `plot()` and `scatter()` functions.

The error message `"ValueError: Unrecognized marker style <marker-style>"` is being shown.

How can I get them to work?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x,y = np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10)
plt.plot(x, y, marker='hline')
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='hline')
```

I am using Spyder 4.1.5, Python 3.8.1.

List of markers showing this error:

"|"     vline

"_"     hline

0 (TICKLEFT)        tickleft

1 (TICKRIGHT)       tickright

2 (TICKUP)      tickup

3 (TICKDOWN)        tickdown

4 (CARETLEFT)       caretleft

5 (CARETRIGHT)      caretright

6 (CARETUP)     caretup

7 (CARETDOWN)       caretdown

8 (CARETLEFTBASE)       caretleft (centered at base)

9 (CARETRIGHTBASE)      caretright (centered at base)

10 (CARETUPBASE)        caretup (centered at base)

11 (CARETDOWNBASE)      caretdown (centered at base)

Comment: Use the value in the `marker` column of that link you referenced. In this case, it will be a `marker="_"`

Comment: Thank you @etch_45 
And do you have any idea about the rest of the markers 0  (TICKLEFT)  to 11 (CARETDOWNBASE).?

Comment: Just use the numeric w/o quotes. See updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value listed in the `marker` column of the link you have referenced is the value to pass into the `marker=" "` parameter for the plot.

Code example `marker="_"` (hline):

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker="_")
```

Yields:[image]

Code example for `marker=11` (caretdown)

```
plt.plot(x,y, marker=11)
```

Yields:

[image]